# ionic, --offset-top issue

Tags: ionic-framework, router

--offset-top: 88px, causes my "ion-content", to not display properly with the header, is there a way to removed this, i have tried "--offset-top: 0px important;" but its not working. Have anyone also experience this?[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the style attribute in the ion-content tags.

[image]